# Updating multiple html input elements using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

Angular 2/4 : Suppose there are three text input html elements. While updating any one, the other two texts should update based on a logic. What is the best way to achieve this using angular. onChange function will not work here as it will do a circular invocation of the same function for each element.

Comment: Can you please add some codes?

Comment: Why do you say you can't bind to the change event? That should work unless you're generating the inputs programmatically inside an ngFor loop. In which case you could just pass the index of your ngFor loop as a parameter to any onchange function in your component, so it will know exactly which one was changed

Comment: Please provide some code explaining your expected behavior? current behavior? and what you have tried so far so others can assist you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make the inputs dependent to each other I think Reactive Forms will be the best solution I think. 
Or If you are stick with template driven , you can make a three separate variables which their value will change according to the change of any of the inputs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to trigger the function to update the other two fields after user unselects the input field then the event you are looking for is `blur`.

You can access the user input in javascript and add your "logic" to determine the text for other auto-filled text fields.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rambo772 if you want the user to leave the input box before you invoke the function, BUT if you want that in realtime, you would simply do the keypress event:

```
<input type=text [(ngModel)]="model" (keypress)="eventHandler($event, model)">

eventHandler(event, model) {
   console.log(event, event.keyCode, event.keyIdentifier, model);
}
```

PS.
To all of you saying that onChange would work, it wont, since the guy has ngModel in every input field, when you trigger one onChange, that would change the other models which would trigger the onChange on them and change the first one.... you see where I'm going with this:), the thing I'm curious about is what the actual problem is, is every input field gonna affect other ones differently, or are they in the same correlation to each other...